# Le mot "Ebola" en français s'est-il écrit "Ébola" (avec un accent)?

Tags: orthographe

Ma question est à propos de [cet article](http://www.iec.cat/scaterm/Butlletins/045.htm#termenoticia2) publié dans le "Butlletí de la Societat Catalana de Terminologia".

D'après cet article, en espagnol, on a commencé à prononcer "Ébola" accentué sur l'antépénultième syllabe en prenant comme point de départ l'orthographe française du mot qui met un accent graphique sur le "e". La raison en est, d'après l'article, que le français est une des langues officielles de la République du Congo. Je suis perplexe avec cet article parce que, en français, j'ai vu toujours ce mot écrit "Ebola" et jamais "Ébola". Quelqu'un peut-il m'éclairer sur cela?

Comment: This has happened often in Spanish and Catalan. See Spanish.SE's [¿Qué palabras provenientes del francés cogieron un acento en la “e” por su escritura francesa, sin que su pronunciación la tuviera?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28949/1674)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour *[Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebola)*

> Ebola (parfois orthographié « Ébola ») peut désigner : ...

Le virus Ebola a été nommé ainsi en référence à *[une rivière](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebola_%28rivi%C3%A8re%29)* passant près de la ville de Yambuku ; cette rivière s'appelait  anciennement *l’Eau blanche*.

Les noms propres n'ont pas de règle grammaticale stricte. Un *E* comme première lettre d'un nom propre a tendance à se prononcer *É* (peut-être parce que l'accent sur une majuscule n'a pas toujours été facile à typographier), sinon on écrirait *Eu*.

P.S. :

- Une recherche avec Etienne renvoie beaucoup d'article qui n'ont pas le *É* souhaitable.
- Il est très compliqué de faire des majuscules accentuées avec les claviers courants.
- Seuls les correcteurs orthographiques (comme celui de ce site) proposent la bonne solution.
- *À bientôt* ou *È* sont possibles [Alt-Gr]+[SHIFT-A] car l'accent grave est positionné en bas à droite de la touche, alors que l'accent aigu ne l'est pas.

Comment: Les accents sur les majuscules en typographie traditionnelle au plomb sont fragiles (l'œil sort du corps, il y a un exemple sur [wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A9nage)).

Comment: É s'écrit à l'aide de la combinaison de touches Alt + 144 sur Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Après avoir lu au sujet de l'origine du nom du virus Ebola et des règles concernant les noms d'origine toponymique:

> Le virus Ebola porte un nom d'origine **toponymique**. C'est le nom de la
>   rivière Ebola, dans le Congo-Kinhasa (ex-Congo belge et ex-Zaïre). Le
>   virus a en effet été identifié en 1976 à l'hôpital de Yambuku, ville
>   située près de l'Ebola.
>
> [...]
>
> Dans le nom de ces virus, je constate qu'on **conserve** la graphie
>   d'origine (Marbug et non Marbourg, Ebola et non Ébola).

Je pense qu'il est préférable de conserver l'orthographe d'origine du lieu, c'est pourquoi tu ne trouves pas Ébola écrit avec un accent.

Answer (score 2):

Une autre raison peut expliquer cet accent « virtuel ».

Tous les mots français commençant par un *E* suivi d'une consonne ne participant pas à une nasalisation (N ou M) sont prononcés comme s'il y avait un accent sur ce *E* (/ɛ/ ou /e/), que cet accent soit présent ou pas.

L'accent est toujours marqué à l'écrit sauf quand le *E* est suit par deux consonnes ou un *X* . Les très rares exceptions sont des mots qui ont gardé une orthographe latine/étrangère comme *ego*, *edelweiss* ou ici *Ebola*.

Comme l'accent est encore souvent omis sur les capitales, tout se passe comme si un accent était en fait présent sur le *E* d'Ebola puisqu'on prononce forcément *ébola* et jamais « *eubola* ».